# express error handler not working with the given http status code and custom message

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

When I am entering localhost://5000/products/

Its showing me all the json objects

But when I am entering localhost://5000/products/(some random id's) It must show me the 404 error with my custom message but its not showing me that.

This is my code:

```
import express from 'express'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
const router = express.Router()
import Product from '../models/productModel.js'

// @Desc Fetch all products
// @Desc GET /api/products
// @access Public
router.get(
    '/', 
asyncHandler(async (req, res) =>{
const products = await Product.find({})

    res.json(products)
}))

// @Desc Fetch single products
// @Desc GET /api/products:id
// @access Public

router.get(
    '/:id',
    asyncHandler(async (req, res) =>{
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)

    if(product) {
        res.json(product)
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ message: 'Product not found' })
    }
}))


export default router
```

Comment: So what **_is_** is showing you? An empty object or string perhaps? Maybe a different error like a 500?

Comment: Is `Product.findById(req.params.id)` rejecting its promise?  If so, it is going to the generic error handler in `asyncHandler()` rather than your custom error.  If so, you will need a try/catch to catch errors from `Product.findById(req.params.id)` so you can show your custom error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat lacking in details, but I do believe I know what's happening. Your idea is that if you pass a non-existent id to the route and mongo does not find it, it will return a 404 - Not Found. Solid logic.

The reason you're not seeing that 404 is, most likely, because you are calling the route with something like `/products/dflhdshfd`. The problem with that is that `findById` only accepts strings that can be **cast** to an `ObjectId`, which, of course `dflhdshfd` cannot be. Hence when you call your route with `/products/dflhdshfd`, your app bombs and throws this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "dflhdshfd" at path "_id" for model "product"
```

And your app does not return anything because you don't handle that error.

As a test, try calling the route like this: `/products/601977b2d2e3cf756b85bc61` and you will see your 404, because `601977b2d2e3cf756b85bc61` can be cast to a valid `ObjectId`.

But more generally, you need to catch errors coming from `Product.findById(req.params.id)` by doing something like this:

```
const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).catch(e => false);
if(product) {
        res.json(product)
} else {
        res.status(404).json({ message: 'Product not found' })
}
```

This way when your `findById` throws an error, it will return false to the `product` variable and your app will return a 404. (*This is not a great way to handle errors and is simply meant to illustrate the point*)

---

**Added**

Properly handling errors can be a daunting task in a large application, so I will address your specific case only while encouraging you to go over [this article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/error/) for a more complete picture.

The way I would handle this specific error is I would first create a small function to route all the caught errors to. Something simple like this:

```
const errorHandler = (err, res) => { //res is the response object
   console.log(err);
   res.status(400).json({msg: "Error has occurred"})
}
```

Then I would rewrite your code like this:

```
router.get(
    '/:id',
    (req, res) => {
        Product.findById(req.params.id)
          .then(product => {
              if(product) {
                  res.json(product)
              } else {
                  res.status(404).json({message: 'Product not found' })
              }
          })
          .catch(e => errorHandler(e, res))  
})
```

Whenever `findById` throws an error, it simply sends it over to `errorHandler` to deal with, while `errorHandler` dumps it to the console for you to troubleshoot and also send a response back to the user.

And that can be the template you adopt for ALL your queries (don't forget to always catch db query errors). Later you can, for example, add a logging feature to `errorHandler` that dumps errors into a file for you to later look at.

So this would be the basic approach I would take here.